# Hide a specific attribute when logging the values of an Object in Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, logging, log4j, slf4j

I'm logging an object values by printing all of its attribute values

```
log("logging obj"+my_obj)
```

I have a "password" attribute in the ojbect which I would like to hide from logging. One strategy I can think of is

```
temporarily save the password value in another String and set the value of the password to null
perform logging
Set the password value again using the value stored in the temp variable
```

Is there a better way of excluding a specific attribute from logging?

Edit: Also I cannot modify my_obj itself by design.

Comment: Depending on how your `password` field is serialized, you could implement and register your own [`Filter`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/spi/Filter.html).

Comment: If this code is actually going to be used for something, you should be hashing+salting passwords wherever possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply override the `toString` method of your object and exclude the password attribute.

e.g:

```
   @Override 
   public String toString()
   {
   StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

   ... add your attributes that should be printed ...

   return result.toString();
   }
```

EDIT: After your comment, I mean something like this:

```
  private String myObjectToString(MyObject myObject)
  {
   StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
   ...
   return result.toString();
  }
```

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to mention that I cannot modify the object by design. But overriding toString does seem like the perfect solution, had I been able to modify the object.

Comment: Just create your own toString()-like method somewhere in your code, passing the object as a parameter and returning a new string which contains all attributes except the password.